# Xsl combine substring-before and a format-number

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to combine a substring-before (take the number without the '-') and a format-number but send error.

I try this XSL:

```
<fo:block text-align="right" margin-right="3px" margin-top="5px">
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number(substring-before(/DTE/pdf/dscDistri/text(), '-'), '#.###,00', 'CL')"/>
</fo:block>
```

XML:

```
<dscDistri>4956,00-</dscDistri>
<dscFinan>1239,00-</dscFinan>
<dscEspec>194,00-</dscEspec>
```

[PDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nawb8.png)

Comment: What does your desired output look like?

Comment: 4956,00-  -->   4.956,00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a typical problem of EU vs. US notation. One solution is using the `translate` function twice. First, use it to convert the string to US format. Then apply `format-string(..)`. Finally convert the string back to EU notation.

This could look like this:

```
<fo:block text-align="right" margin-right="3px" margin-top="5px">
    <xsl:value-of select="translate(format-number(translate(substring-before(DTE/pdf/dscDistri/text(), '-'),',.','.,'), '#,###.00'),'.,',',.')"/>
</fo:block>
```

**Output:**

```
<fo:block...>4.956,00</fo:block>
```

This is ugly, but the XSLT spec is US-centric. So it's a bad situation for EU-people.

Comment: As of today, the UK is part of the EU; so are other countries like Ireland that use "." rather than "," as a decimal separator. The EU is not a single "locale" in I18N terms.

Answer (score 0):

it can be that you are using a wrong format.
try 
 #,###.00 instead of #.###,00

Comment: it's working in another one without the '-'
It's CLP, not dollars.